# Date addition in postgres jpql

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jpql

If I query like below we get data with oracle db with jpql.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("postgres");
    EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        String jpqlQuery = "SELECT coalesce(c.actualDateTime, "
                + "coalesce("
                + "c.propDepDateTime+"
                + "TO_NUMBER(c.estOnDateTime-c.estOffDateTime),"
                + "c.estOnDateTime )) FROM Flight c  ";
        
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpqlQuery);
        List<Object> objects = query.getResultList();

        objects.stream().forEach((x) -> System.out.println(x));
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    } finally {

        entityManager.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
@Entity
@Table(name = "FLIGHT")
public class Flight {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ACT_DATETIME", columnDefinition = "Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date actualDateTime;

    @Column(name = "PROPAG_DEP_DATETIME", columnDefinition = "Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date propDepDateTime;

    @Column(name = "EST_ON_DATETIME", columnDefinition = "Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date estOnDateTime;

    @Column(name = "EST_OFF_DATETIME", columnDefinition = "Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date estOffDateTime;
```

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS flight;

CREATE TABLE flight(
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY , 
ACT_DATETIME TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
PROPAG_DEP_DATETIME TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
EST_ON_DATETIME TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
EST_OFF_DATETIME TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO flight(ID,ACT_DATETIME, PROPAG_DEP_DATETIME,EST_ON_DATETIME,EST_OFF_DATETIME)
VALUES(
    1,(SELECT now()::timestamp),(SELECT now()::timestamp+1 * INTERVAL '1 DAY'),(SELECT now()::timestamp+2* INTERVAL '1 DAY'),
    (SELECT now()::timestamp+3* INTERVAL '1 DAY')
);
```

On migrating to Postgres I changed jpql as below, but throwing ERROR:

```
operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + numeric
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Tried multiplying by interval etc. but not worked yet. Any helps welcome.

```java
String jpqlQuery = "SELECT coalesce(c.actualDateTime, "
                    + "coalesce("
                    + "c.propDepDateTime+("
                    + "TO_NUMBER(quote_literal(c.estOnDateTime-c.estOffDateTime),'99999999.99999999')),"
                    + "c.estOnDateTime )) FROM Flight c  ";
```

Comment: `(SELECT now()::timestamp)` can be simplified to `now()`

Comment: Sorry, Unabled to edit post. On editing it tells, "my post is more code. Add more details". 
For select I get problem. Insert is working fine as it executed in pgadmin.

Comment: There is no need to change it in the question, just fix your actual code. There is no need to prefix function calls with `select` when they are used inside an expression. Did you use `values ( (select sysdate from dual), (select sysdate + 1 from dual))` in Oracle?

Comment: done in actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Written & registered below custom function in custom PostgreDialect &
changed (c.actualDateTime-c.propDepDateTime) in postgres jpql query to to_interval(c.actualDateTime-c.propDepDateTime) fixed this problem. Thanks
[https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name|](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name%7C)

```
registerFunction("to_interval", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP, "cast(?1 as interval)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract one timestamp from another, you get an `interval` not a number, so passing the result of `c.estOnDateTime-c.estOffDateTime` to `to_number()` would result in an error as well. You are then trying to add that number (which is invalid to begin with) to a `timestamp` which is also not allowed.

The use of `quote_literal()` makes no sense whatsoever in that context.

But you can add an interval to a timestamp, so as far as I can tell, the following should do what you want:

```
coalesce(c.actualDateTime, 
         coalesce(c.propDepDateTime + (c.estOnDateTime-c.estOffDateTime),               
                  c.estOnDateTime) 
         )
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f6bd2177086d6eff531cbe8489d7e674)

Comment: ``` SELECT coalesce(c.actualDateTime, coalesce(c.propDepDateTime + (c.estOnDateTime-c.estOffDateTime), c.estOnDateTime) ) FROM Flight c

thrown error operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + timestamp without time zone :(

Comment: Then you are running something else, because that expression does work (after adjusting the column names): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f6bd2177086d6eff531cbe8489d7e674 Maybe your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") messes with the code. But the SQL **is** valid

Comment: omg. In pgadmin it will work. But my problem is jpql which hibernate executes :|